# Combine 3 SQL queries in to one

Tags: sql, windows

I have three queries and I want them to display in one table with three columns. I researched but could not able to get it done correctly. Any help would be highly appriciated.

below are my three queries.

1. select count(NodeID) AS Total_Ports from UDT_Port where IsMonitored = 'True'
2. select count(NodeID) AS Free_Ports from UDT_Port where IsMonitored = 'True' and
   operationalStatus NOT Like '%1%'
3. Select
   (select
   count(NodeID) AS Total_Ports
   from
   (
   select * from UDT_Port where IsMonitored = 'True'
   ) a )-
   (select count(NodeID) AS Free_Ports
   from
   (
   select * from UDT_Port where IsMonitored = 'True' and
   operationalStatus NOT Like '%1%'
   ) b) as Used_Ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a single pass query along with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsMonitored = 'True' THEN 1 END) AS Total_Ports,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsMonitored = 'True' AND operationalStatus NOT LIKE '%1%'
               THEN 1 END) AS Free_Ports,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsMonitored = 'True' THEN 1 END) -
        COUNT(CASE WHEN IsMonitored = 'True' AND
                        operationalStatus NOT LIKE '%1%'
                   THEN 1 END) AS Used_Ports
FROM UDT_Port;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response, but im getting this error when i tried to run,.....Msg 8153, Level 0, State 1, Line 1
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @diniththaruka Unless that error is preventing the query from executing, you may ignore it, assuming my answer generates the output you are expecting here.